# Changing cell value for a range of cells without multiple if statments

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change the color of a cell based on the value of an adjacent cell. The following code is working properly for a single cell, but I would like it to apply to a range of cells, currently it looks at the value of S5 and changes to color of T5, I would like this to iterate for a range of cells (S5 to S100 matching with T5 to T100). How can I do this without needing to make an if statement for 100 cells?

```
If LCase(Sheets(1).Range("S5").Value) = "yes" Then
    Sheets(1).Range("T5").Interior.ColorIndex = 33

ElseIf Sheets(1).Range("S5").Value <> "" Then
    Sheets(1).Range("T5").Interior.ColorIndex = 19

Else
    Sheets(1).Range("T5").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
```

Comment: Conditional formatting?

Comment: @findwindow is right that conditional formatting will likely be easier than VBA - unless you have other VBA things, in which case you might prefer this method. In short, you will need to create a loop which creates a counter and looks at each row of S that you care about.

Comment: I would use conditional formatting like @fndwindow stated, but if you want to keep it in vba, then look into `for` loops to iterate through a given range.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, you could do something like this:

```
For i = 5 to 100

    If LCase(Sheets(1).Range("S"&i).Value) = "yes" Then
        Sheets(1).Range("T"&i).Interior.ColorIndex = 33

    ElseIf Sheets(1).Range("S"&i).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets(1).Range("T"&i).Interior.ColorIndex = 19

    Else
        Sheets(1).Range("T"&i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Note how instead of referring directly to "S5", instead the code refers to Si [for whatever number i is, starting at 5 and going row by row up to 100].

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting in EXCEL would probably be the best way to handle this:

- [Conditional Formatting](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format9_2010.php)

Grade 'Eh' Bacon gave a good solution for doing this, and it is acceptable. Here is another solution that should work fine and allows some different math based Column/Row solutions if you need to make these actions more modular.

```
Set myRange = Range("S5:S100")

For Each cell in myRange
    If LCase(cell.Value) = "yes" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
    ElseIf LCase(cell.Value) = "no" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next
```

[Range Offset Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting way to do this:

```
Const FORMULA = "CHOOSE(MMULT(--(~>{""yerz"",""""}),{1;1})+1,0,19,33)"
With [t5:t100]
    v = Evaluate(Replace(FORMULA, "~", .Address))
    For i = 1 To .Count
        .Item(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = v(i, 1)
    Next
End With
```

This small solution packs a lot of learning opportunities that can be leveraged far beyond this question.

Notice that your color numbers can be edited at the end of the first line.

Here is what is happening.

We use the Evaluate function to evaluate a formula that takes your range of values `T5:T100` and produces an array of color numbers.

We then assign each value in the array to the ColorIndex of the cell to the right.

The challenging part is creating the formula that will result in the appropriate array of color numbers.  :)